# HGST HE8 8TB Hard Drive fails

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

just received my 8TB Hard drive HGST.

The problem is next:

I bought an Sata enclosure so I can use it as USB (3.0)

I've formated it to NTFS and all worked fine, I copied some files inside it, then I Safely ejected the HDD then plugged in again and it couldn't mount, according to GParted, I get this message:

```
The device /dev/sdb1 doesn't exist

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

Also, is making strange noises while I'm using

So, in order to make it work, I did this:

```
ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

So I copied some files inside it and safely ejected it, then I plugged in again and I get this message:

```
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "50BA159D16ED73B1":
Error when getting information for file '/media/test/50BA159D16ED73B1/parkfun.mp4': Input output error.
```

But, as you can see here:

```
/dev/sdb1                    7,3T  1,3G  7,3T   1% /media/test/
```

There really are contents inside the HDD but their don't show up.

I've googled everything that could help me with my problem, but I'm kinda lost and I hope you guys can short this out.

Thank you!

Comment: If using NTFS, you need Windows or Windows repair disk as Linux cannot run chkdsk. The ntfsfix only turns on the chkdsk needed flag. Are you using gpt partitioning? Also some external drive caddy do not support gpt or very large drives. And if you originally partitioned with Windows 8 or 10, it will leave it hibernated. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred hi there, no I'm not using windows and I don't need windows, I bought the HDD for backups, big backups, maybe my laptop doesn't accept bigger hard drives like 8TB? I have an ASUS Rog 32GB ram, 512GB SSD, 2TBHDD all internal, and I bought this new hard drive. It's really stressfull and I don't know what to do, shall I return it and buy a smaller one? What about this tutorial I found for HDDs bigger than 2TB ? http://dev-random.net/creating-mounting-partition-lager-2-tb-linux/

Comment: I suggest you format it as EXT4 instead of NTFS

Comment: Hi again, I've formatted it to EXT4 too, same problems. Now I've formated it to FAT32, copied some files, and same problem, not showing up, or the files are corrupted.

Comment: run sync command  as root before the unmount next time and see if it fix your issues

Comment: Absolutely do not use FAT32. It cannot support any file over 4GB and has no journal so chkdsk can take a long time, perhaps days with your drive. Some users with issues just purchased a new drive caddy that supported larger drives. Does your drive caddy say it supports very large drives? Big drive for backups means when it fails you loose a lot of data. May be better to have 3 smaller drives and rotate them. You need versioned backups & more than one place for data.

Comment: Well I've formated it again to NTFS and worked fine, but the speed of copying files is decreasing everytime, and also there are lots of scratching noises. I think the Enclosure I bought is not giving enough power to the hard drive, but I will definitely return the HDD and buy smallers as @oldfred suggested because if one drive fails, I'm f*cked up.

Comment: @oldfred As recommended by a friend, HGST are the best hard drives if you care about durability, he owns a datacenter and he has the same damn HGST hard drives for more than 13 years without any problems.
In my case, I'm just a simple Laptop user, so, what hard drive do you recommend me to buy in order to get around 5-10TB ? I saw a nice Seagate HDD 5TB 10000RPM but people complain a lot about Seagate, if I can't use HGST, then what other product shall I use? Thank you!

Comment: I do not know brands/models of hard drives. I have had failures in 1 year but most drives do last longer. But after about 3 years, I demote drive to backup and get a new daily use drive. I now have SSD as boot drive but still  a HDD for data.